# Do azure linux vm supports ip based virtual hosting?

Tags: linux, azure, linux-networking, azure-networking

I have tried by attaching a second interface with a second public ip.But Iam unable to use that public ip.For ip based virtual hosting i need 2 public ip.(iam using ubuntu 16 vm)How to overcome this problem?Any solution?
[screen shot of  second nic attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PA5Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use 2 Public IPs for your VM, you can also assign multiple IPs for your VM without adding multiple NICs.

Scenario:

[image]

Steps:

1. Create a new Public IP resource.
2. Associate the public IP address resource to a new IP configuration in the NiC of your VM

After associating a Public address resource to a new IP configuration or an existing IP configuration, you still **need to add the private IP addresses to your VM OS**.

> Review the new IP configuration. Even though a private IP address
>   wasn't explicitly assigned, one was automatically assigned to the IP
>   configuration, because all IP configurations must have a private IP
>   address.

SSH your Azure Linux VM and Complete the following steps for your VM operating system (Ubuntu):

1. Make sure you are the root user. If you are not, enter the following command:`sudo -i`
2. Update the configuration file of the network interface (assuming ‘eth0’).

   Keep the existing line item for dhcp. The primary IP address remains configured as it was previously.

   Add a configuration for an additional static IP address with the following commands:
   `cd /etc/network/interfaces.d/
   ls`

   You should see a `.cfg` file
3. Open the file. You should see the following lines at the end of the file 
   `auto eth0 
   iface eth0 inet dhcp`
4. Add the following lines after the lines that exist in this file:
   `iface eth0 inet static 
   address <your private IP address here> 
   netmask <your subnet mask>`

**NOTE:Add each of the secondary private IP addresses to the NIC with the same subnet specified for the primary IP address.**

5. Save the file by using the following command:`:wq`
6. Reset the network interface with the following command:`sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0`

**Important**

**Run both ifdown and ifup in the same line if using a remote connection.**

7. Verify the IP address is added to the network interface with the following command:`ip addr list eth0`

   You should see the IP address you added as part of the list.

You can see more details about how to Assign multiple IP addresses to virtual machines using the Azure portal in [this official document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal).  Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi, @arunmohan . If this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as answer , so that we can help more people. Thanks~

Comment: @Yang....k dude..It helped me..

Comment: Hi,@arun mohan. I'm very gald to hear that this answer is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

With multiple NICs in Linux VM's, you will need to create routing rules, otherwise only the primary NIC will work.

The Azure documentation has outlined the necessary steps [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/multiple-nics). See the 'Configure guest OS for multiple NICs' section.

However, when I was hitting this issue with CentOS a while ago, it didn't help me much. You may want to have a look at this [article](http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/ConfigureRouting) as well, which solved it for me.